# Refreshing Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, refresh, uilabel

I have two viewcontrollers in my storyboard project. Once I click the tableview row in ViewcontrollerOne then it will display the contents of that row by passing value and settext to that labels in viewcontrollerTwo. But when I tried a third viewcontroller and by clicking the button is third viewcontroller am sending same arrayname with different values but its not displaying in the label in viewcontrollerTwo.

Why? How can I refresh the viewcontroller on viewdidload or while moving to viewcontrollerTwo ?

Currently, I add this code to viewcontrollerTwo's `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: well if you want you could also call [yourcustomcontroller.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

You can reload your view controller by putting this in your `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
[yourcontroller reloadInputViews];
```

However, why don't you reload your tableview as you are using same tableview.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use NSNotificationCenter to update your parent viewcontroller

At your parent viewcontroller put this:

```
//since child view controller calls turnItOff, notification center calls function "turnButtonCountinuesOff"
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(turnButtonCountinuesOff) name:@"turnItOff" object:nil];
```

turnButtonCountinuesOff is your function at parent viewcontroller

At your child viewcontroller put this:

```
//connect to parent UI view controller calls notification turnItOff.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"turnItOff" object:nil];
```

hope it helps.